# counting lines of input using memchr fails

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I wrote a program to count lines of input given by stdin :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE  8192
#define RS  '\n'

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
    ssize_t n;
    char *r; 
    int c = 0;

    readchunk:
    n = read(0, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
    if (n<=0) goto end; // EOF
    r=buff;

    searchrs:
    r = memchr(r, RS, n);
    if(r!=NULL) {
        c++;
        if((r-buff)<n) {
            ++r;
            goto searchrs;
        }
    }
    goto readchunk;

    end:
    printf("%d\n", ++c);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with gcc, with no options.

When run, it gives unstable result, not far from truth but false. Sometimes it segfaults. The bigger is the buffer size the more often it segfaults.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You should start abandonning the abuse of `goto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building your program with `-fsanitize=address` and feeding it sufficiently long input produces:

```
==119818==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffedbba1500 at pc 0x7fc4d56fd574 bp 0x7ffedbb9f4a0 sp 0x7ffedbb9ec50
READ of size 8192 at 0x7ffedbba1500 thread T0
    #0 0x7fc4d56fd573  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4+0x40573)
    #1 0x563fdf5f4b90 in main /tmp/t.c:23
    #2 0x7fc4d533e2b0 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x202b0)
    #3 0x563fdf5f49c9 in _start (/tmp/a.out+0x9c9)

Address 0x7ffedbba1500 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 8224 in frame
    #0 0x563fdf5f4ab9 in main /tmp/t.c:11

  This frame has 1 object(s):
    [32, 8224) 'buff' <== Memory access at offset 8224 overflows this variable
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism or swapcontext
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4+0x40573)
```

Line 23 is the call to `memchr`.

When you increment `r`, you should probably decrement `n`.